# Is the massive Fierz-Pauli action invariant under changes of coordinates?

Tags: gravity, coordinate-systems, gauge-invariance, linearized-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

The action for linearlized gravity on a curved background has the form

$S_{LinGrav}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G} \int d^{4} x \;\sqrt{-g}\;\left[-\frac{1}{4} \nabla_{\rho} h_{\mu \nu} \nabla^{\rho} h^{\mu \nu} + \frac{1}{2} \nabla_{\rho} h_{\mu \nu} \nabla^{\nu} h^{\rho \mu} + \frac{1}{4} \nabla_{\mu} h \nabla^{\mu} h-\frac{1}{2} \nabla_{\mu} h^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\nu} h\right],$

and possesses the gauge symmetry

$h_{\mu\nu}\to h_{\mu\nu}+\delta h_{\mu\nu}=h_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\mu\xi_\nu+\partial_\nu\xi_\mu.$

The Fierz-Pauli action for massive gravitons is obtained by adding to this action a mass term that goes like

$\frac{m^2}{4} \int d^4x \;\sqrt{-g}\left(h_{\mu\nu}h^{\mu\nu}-h^2\right).$

Adding this term makes longitudinal modes physical and breaks gauge invariance (pretty much in the same way as adding the Proca mass to the Maxwell action breaks local U(1) invariance). My question is the following:

Under a coordinate transformation $x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\alpha(x^\mu)$, the mass term transforms as a scalar since all the indices in this expression are contracted. Thus, it should be invariant under a change of coordinates of the form

$h_{\mu\nu}\longrightarrow h'_{\mu\nu}= \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu} h_{\alpha\beta}.$

The same happens with all the other terms in the action $S_{LinGrav}$, as well as with the volume $(d^{4} x \sqrt{-g})$. However, the action should not be invariant under diffeomorphisms (whose infinitesimal form is leads to $\delta h_{\mu\nu}$ above) when the mass term is added. How can I understand this?

Answer (score 2):

The mass term is not invariant under linearized diffeomorphisms since, as you mentioned, it is not invariant under $h_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow h_{\mu \nu} + \partial_{\mu} \xi_{\nu} + \partial_{\nu} \xi_{\mu}$. Your argument about contracting indices would be correct if they were contracted using the full metric $g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$ (I am assuming that you are linearizing about the Minkowski metric). However, in this linearized theory, the contractions in the mass term are made using the Minkowski metric, not the perturbed metric.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. But then is the massive action is invariant under coordinate transformations $x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\alpha(x^\mu)$, $h_{\mu\nu}\longrightarrow h'_{\mu\nu}= \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu} h_{\alpha\beta}$ ?

Comment: No, since you are working in the linearized theory, and this is precisely the same as adding $\partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu$ to $h_{\mu \nu}$.